# Why the standard function "__libc_start_main" is not compiled with an extra underscore("_") prefix?

Tags: c, assembly

I am a programmer using Java and C for a few years, recently I am reading the book **Advanced C and C++ Compiling**, from which I learned that some functions are invoked before the main is called, like the "_start", the "__libc_start_main". Those details must be explained and answered hundreds of time here by C experts.

But I noticed a very very tiny things that, with the common function invocation conventions in C like the cdecl, when we write a function, its name will be prefixed with an underscore '_' after compiled. That means if you have a function called foo, it will be compiled as _foo in the final assembly text. Inversely, if we found a section called _start in the assembly text, it should having a mapping function called "start" in C.

Am I right? If so, the "__libc_start_main" in the assembly text should have its function signature as "_libc_start_main" (one less underscore prefix) in C ?

```
080482d0 <_start>:
80482d0:       31 ed                   xor    %ebp,%ebp
80482d2:       5e                      pop    %esi
80482d3:       89 e1                   mov    %esp,%ecx
80482d5:       83 e4 f0                and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
80482d8:       50                      push   %eax
80482d9:       54                      push   %esp
80482da:       52                      push   %edx
80482db:       68 50 84 04 08          push   $0x8048450
80482e0:       68 e0 83 04 08          push   $0x80483e0
80482e5:       51                      push   %ecx
80482e6:       56                      push   %esi
80482e7:       68 d0 83 04 08          push   $0x80483d0
80482ec:       e8 cf ff ff ff          call   80482c0   <__libc_start_main@plt>
80482f1:       f4                      hlt
80482f2:       66 90                   xchg   %ax,%ax
```

I know this is not right obviously because if you google it, hundreds of sites will show you that its signature is exactly same as it is marked and called in assembly. Can any C expert explain this?

```
int __libc_start_main(
    int (*main)(int, char **, char **), int argc, char **argv,
    int (*init)(int, char **, char **), void (*fini)(void),
    void (*ldso_fini)(void)) ;
```

Comment: You don't mention your OS, but this looks like Linux, in which case *no* functions get implicit `_`s.

Comment: All functions or just those implemention-ralated functions ?

Comment: no functions...